# Can WebRTC help me create a virtual classroom?

Tags: webrtc, video-conferencing

I'm trying to create a virtual classroom. Since I'm not familiar with the web conferencing (or conferencing) terminology, I'm not sure if I'm understanding WebRTC's capabilities as I should.

I've looked in the examples for WebRTC, and all that I've found seem to be peer-to-peer connections. As I understand it, peer-to-peer connections are between two entities. However, virtual classrooms are different as far as I know; they require all parties to be connected to each other, so that when one user speaks/types, all users hear her.

Is such a thing possible with WebRTC? If so, what is it called and how can I read more about it?

Comment: Yes, but I would use a centralized MCU for all your connections. [The Janus-Gateway](https://github.com/meetecho/janus-gateway) is a good example of this.

Comment: It'll be a huge task.  Have you looked at the open source Big Blue Button project?  They're currently Flash based but are actively moving towards webRTC.

Comment: @mtbikemike No, i hadn't. Your suggestion was great though; now I don't have to deal with writing my own loooots of code thanks to you. However, the current existing answer covers my original question. So I'm kind of stuck which answer to accept; your answer made me realize I'm on the wrong path, while the current (only) answer gives me an answer to my question. :)

Comment: @parham-doustdar I'll just post an answer then :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the open source Big Blue Button project (http://bigbluebutton.org/).  They're currently Flash based but are actively moving towards webRTC.  Rumor has it they'll be using Kurento as their MCU.  They also have open source mobile (Android/iOS) application code.

Answer (score 2):

According to http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/infrastructure/, such a thing is possible:

```
Beyond one-to-one: multi-party WebRTC

You may also want to take a look at Justin Uberti's proposed IETF standard for 
a REST API for access to TURN Services.

It's easy to imagine use cases for media streaming that go beyond a simple 
one-to-one call: for example, video conferencing between a group of colleagues, 
or a public event with one speaker and hundreds (or millions) of viewers.

A WebRTC app can use multiple RTCPeerConnections so to that every endpoint
connects to every other endpoint in a mesh configuration. This is the approach 
taken by apps such as talky.io, and works remarkably well for a small handful 
of peers. Beyond that, processing and bandwidth consumption becomes excessive, 
especially for mobile clients.
```

Maybe you can try searching in the [webrtc google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/discuss-webrtc)

hope this helps